# How to extract substrings and numbers from curl result using grep or other method

Tags: regex, curl, awk, grep, extract

This is my first question/post, and I’m very new to using regular expressions.  Despite lots of searching and experimenting (e.g., -o and -w options), I can’t seem to make the following work (and I'm too embarrassed to post all of my failed attempts, but see the end of the post).  I’m trying to pull some weather details (status, temperature, and wind information) from a web site.

I’m using the following statement to extract the appropriate information into a text file, which I then want to grep to extract the information.  Current weather is listed at the top, so I only need the first few lines (head -n 7).  You can visit the site (https://wttr.in/[city]) and enter a [city] to see the diversity of results.

curl -s wttr.in/fargo | head -n 7 > ~/Downloads/weather.cache

Here’s are the problems/challenges I’ve faced:

1. There is some “stick” art on every line, which is color-coded.  These codes get pulled into the text file, along with the “sticks” text.
2. Current weather status could be one word (Sunny) or multiple words (Partly cloudy).  I want everything.
3. Temperature could be a single number (5 °F), a range (0-15 °F), and of course negative numbers are possible (-10--5 °F ).  I need all the information.
4. Wind direction and speed (↘ 8 mph).  Again, speed can be a range (5-16 mph).  Wind direction is a special/unicode character, which I want to capture.
5. I want to assign each items (#2-4) to its own variable without any extra stuff from the line.

Ideal results from my above example, which will be used in a status bar, would be as follows.

Weather = “Sunny”

Temp = “-22--5 °F”

Wind = “↘ 8 mph”

Any assistance would be most appreciated.  Apologies in advance as I struggled to correctly format this post.

## Background

Actual website view is below, but without the color-coding for the "Sun" stick figure and "8" (wind speed).  Note:  the color-coding isn't right, due to the posting software (and probably my lack of knowledge).  So, it might be helpful to go to the original site (https://wwtr.in/fargo).

```
Weather report: Fargo, United States of America

         \   /     Sunny
          .-.      -22--5 °F      
       - (   ) -   ↘ 8 mph        
          `_'      9 mi           
         /   \     0.0 in 



Curl result is below, which is being stored in the weather cache file I'm working with.

Weather report: Fargo, United States of America

 [38;5;226m    \   /    [0m Sunny
 [38;5;226m     .-.     [0m [38;5;021m-22[0m-[38;5;021m-5[0m °F[0m      
 [38;5;226m  ― (   ) ―  [0m [1m↘[0m [38;5;226m8[0m mph[0m        
 [38;5;226m     `-’     [0m 9 mi[0m           
 [38;5;226m    /   \    [0m 0.0 in[0m
```

===

## Some Attempts

As an example with temperature, here's the closest I've come.

```
egrep --regexp='-?[[:digit:]].*°F'


  .-.      -22--5 °F
```

Failed attempts include (also tried -w option).

```
    grep -m 1 -Eo -e '-?[[:digit:]].*°F'

38;5;226m     .-.      -22--5 °F
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you trying to create the page you have displayed in the Background or are you trying to parse the page you have displayed in the background? Basically, it would awesome to succinctly see some raw text you are trying to mine with an example of what you are trying to produce.

Comment: I was interested in parsing the part of the page, but it wasn't "clean enough" for a beginner like myself.  I'm not doing anything fancy, just trying to pull and insert some information into my i3 status bar (now back on my to-do list -- nothing to share right now).  I know that other status bars have pre-built weather modules, but I wanted to take the opportunity to learn some web scrapping and text extraction methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lynx instead of curl and you won't get all the formatting chars:

```
$ lynx --dump 'https://wttr.in/fargo' | head
Weather report: Fargo, United States of America

     \   /     Sunny
      .-.      -11-1 °F
   ― (   ) ―   ↘ 8 mph
      `-’      9 mi
     /   \     0.0 in
                                                       ┌─────────────┐

┌──────────────────────────────┬───────────────────────┤  Mon 18 Feb ├────────
```

.

```
$ lynx --dump 'https://wttr.in/fargo' |
awk '
    BEGIN{ split("_ _ Weather Temp Wind",m) }
    NR>2 && NR in m{ sub(/.*  /,""); print m[NR] " = \"" $0 "\"" }
'
Weather = "Sunny"
Temp = "-11-1 °F"
Wind = "↘ 8 mph"
```

Comment: In a separate context, I had used lynx, but not any of the options.  Time to learn some awk, though.  Wow, it never ceases to amaze me how a few lines of code (and the right program/command) can solve an issue.  Thank you for sharing your expertise.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be boring to point out that the API allows for downloading in other ways?

eg. various shortform formats like:

```
curl "http://wttr.in/Fargo?format=4"
curl "http://wttr.in/Fargo?format=%l:%c:%t:%w"
```

or html:

```
curl -H 'User-Agent: mozilla/compatible' http://wttr.in/Fargo
```

The latter helpfully inserts logical markup.

Another way to strip the ANSI escapes is:

```
curl -s http://wttr.in/Fargo | head -7 | colorize --clean-all
```

if you have the `colorize` utility (available with various linux distributions).

Comment: Yup, I completely missed the link for API details.  Lesson learned.  Your added comments about inserting logical markup, stripping the escapes, and using a color utility were all helpful options, especially as I want do some other focused web scrapping tasks.  Always great to learn.  Thanks.